# I am converting char zip code to INT in SQL and I need to preserve the leading zero if there is one

Tags: sql

Using SQL, how do I convert a 5 digit zip code in integer format to a character format and still preserve the leading zero if there is one?

Comment: Integer data types represent numeric integers, which don't change value whether they're written as '40' or '000040'. If you want to retain their _string representations_, use a string type.

Comment: Store it as an integer, and format it when you retrieve it

Comment: And the UI representation should probably be done .... at ... the .. UI LEVEL

Answer (score 3):

If you store a number as a number in SQL, it will always remove the leading zero. You are telling SQL that it's a number, and a number doesn't need leading zeros.

2 options are to:

1) Save it as a string and convert it to a number in your application

2) Save it as a number and format it with leading 0's in your application

Comment: Actually, option 1 will also truncate the leading 0's, it will just do it in the application rather than the database.